# How do I not reuse positions in Listview?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I'm having a problem where I have a listview that receives multiple items from an array. These items are phrases from diverse authors. I created a check box to bookmark. So when the author's favorite sentence 1 is marked, it is written to the sharedPreference and transferred to a new activity. When a favorite mark of sentence 1 of author B, it simply replaces the marking of sentence 1 of author A.

Then I noticed that each position inside the listview repeats, for example: Author A> sentence 1 -> has position 0 Author B> sentence 1 -> has position 0

For this reason I can not record the phrases that are in different items, but in the same position in the favorites, I do not know if it would be possible to get the position inside the array instead of the listview, because there you could get the real position that would not repeat itself or If possible do not repeat it in the listview.

My code is this:

```
// DECLARANDO COMPONENTES

    private ListView lista;
    private AlertDialog alerta;
    private String[] frasesR;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frase_autor_frase);

    // VINCULANDO COMPONENTES

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_id);



        // VERIFICANDO VALOR NULO E ADICIONANDO NO ARRAY

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        List<String> textos = new ArrayList<>();
        int numeroDeTextos = 911;

        for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeTextos; i++) {
            String texto = extra.getString("texto" + i);

            // Verifica se é nulo ou vázio.
            if (texto == null || texto.trim().length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            textos.add(texto);
        }

            // CRIANDO O ARRAY

            final String[] frases = textos.toArray(new String[0]);


            // ENVIANDO FRASES PARA PARAMETRO GLOBAL

                frasesR = frases;



            // UTILIZANDO O ADPTADOR PARA RECEBER O LISTVIEW

            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (


                            // Primeiro Parametro do Array Adpater é o Context

                            getApplicationContext(),

                            // Segundo Parametro do Array Adpater é o Layout

                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1,

                            // Terceiro Parametro do Array Adapter é indicar o nome do Array para exibição

                            frasesR

                    );

            lista.setAdapter(adaptador);




            // EVENTO DE CLIQUE

           lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {


                   // CHECK BOX

                   View checkBoxView = View.inflate(FraseAutorFrase.this, R.layout.checkbox, null);

                   CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                           // Save to shared preferences

                           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
                           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                           editor.putString("frase"+position, frasesR[position]);
                           editor.commit();


                       }
                   });
                   checkBox.setText("Marcar como Favorito?");
```

Comment: Android recycles list items for performance purposes. It is highly recommended to reuse them if you want your ListView to scroll smoothly, It will be performance issue if you want in every change to generate new view and connect to the adapter.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that position is declared as final (constant)

Comment: Thanks, Roger
The problem was the 'final'.